# Please undelete this answer

Tags: discussion, status-declined, vote-to-undelete

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294854/1767412

Although the above, now deleted answer references non MySQL join types, it's still better than the accepted answer which does the same thing.

I don't understand why we would be deleting such a highly useful and highly upvoted answer and not sure how else to make this request but please undelete.

Comment: It was for sure deleted for plagiarism or something similar since a Moderator was involved (it sounds a link-only answer by the way)

Comment: The author cited a source so clearly didn't claim to have created the illustration.  I get that it's basically a link only answer but it's got 468 upvotes.  This is content that many people found useful - including myself.  If it's going to stay deleted I'd really like an explanation

Comment: it's link-only, as well as inaccessible. Images are terrible for accessibility and links die fast. If it additionally explained the difference between them in text instead of using inaccessible images, it wouldn't have been deleted (... provided it wasn't plagiarism obviously)

Comment: upvotes/bounties/accepted are all irrelevant when judging if the answer need to be deleted or not. A link-only answer is a link-only answer and should be deleted. It's *unfair* to get all these upvotes by simply saying *look here, you will get the answer* (you should use comment for this)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - It's not really a link only answer though is it? it's an **image only answer** with a couple of additional links.

Comment: an image taken from somewhere + two links so there is no content written by the author

Comment: Related discussion on [image-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122091/a-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-words)

Comment: The image is actually from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins under a CPOL license.

Comment: The content is not useful. See my comments on the answer & at the duplicate page. Unfortunately, my first comment on it (briefly explaining problems with the diagram & the links & pointing to my comments at the duplicate page) was deleted along with a reply by the asker.

Comment: It was useful to me and I thought it was a cool image so deserved to stay. Someone even commented that they printed it out and put it on their wall so I guess I'm not the only one who felt this way. On the bright side, I've managed to set a new personal record garnering the most downvotes ever on a single post.

Comment: "It was useful to me and I thought it was a cool image" - right. "so deserved to stay" - right! ... but there is something missing in that statement. "On the web". It deserves to stay on the web. Not necessarily on Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a replacement for the web, nor a replacement for search engines such as Google. Since it was referenced off-site, after removal from Stack Overflow it actually did remain on the web.

Comment: "You are doing just what thousands of others have done--got a vague impression you (wrongly) assume makes sense." "What is the legend for the diagrams?" [Venn Diagram for Natural Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642928/3404097) Etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the answer's current state, it will not be undeleted. It is not a suitable answer for this site and does not meet our minimum requirements, independent of its technical merit (or lack thereof). As such, I'm declining this request.

However, at your reputation and privilege level, you can edit other people's deleted answers. If you want this salvaged, then **do so**. At that point, you can update this Meta question or flag that answer for moderator attention to have it reconsidered for undeletion.

Comment: On what grounds do you say that *"it is not a suitable answer"*? Because it is link (and image) only? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: There are at least 3 reasons that I noticed after a quick glance. It being image-only is definitely one of them.

Comment: You see? I just had a flag declined on [this post that is entirely quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31528459/3404097). Well, at least it isn't merely unexplained images, it constitutes a coherent exposition. Wish I could figure out what the flagging criteria are.

Comment: @philipxy Yes, I declined that flag. There's nothing wrong with an answer that contains properly attributed quotations. I don't understand why *you* think there is something wrong with it.

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3404097) OK? PS I am still researching. I cannot see anything official that invalidates image-only answers, even though you say "being image-only is definitely" a reason to delete. I can't find anything official about link-only answers being invalid either.

Comment: Not really interested in lawyering this out. That's not what mods do. We clean up garbage. If it's extremely low quality or causing harm/distraction in our judgment, we delete it. Simple as that.